# Is it good to get married at a time of tribulation?

Tags: matthew, 1-timothy, marriage, olivet-discourse

New American Standard Bible Matthew 24:

> 19 But **woe to those women who are pregnant**, and to those who are nursing babies in those days! 20Moreover, pray that when you flee, it will not be in the winter, or on a Sabbath. 21For then there will be a great tribulation, such as has not occurred since the beginning of the world until now, nor ever will again.

According to Jesus, it's a bad idea to be pregnant at a time of tribulation.

1 Timothy 4:

> 1 But the Spirit explicitly says that in later times some will fall away from the faith, paying attention to deceitful spirits and teachings of demons, 2 by means of the hypocrisy of liars seared in their own conscience as with a branding iron, 3a who **forbid marriage**

According to Paul, it is okay to get married in a time of tribulation.

What's wrong with forbidding marriage since Jesus warned about being pregnant in that kind of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, in that Matthew 24 quote, Jesus *never* said, "Don't get married!" He simply warned that a time was coming when pregnant women and those with babies would have the most awful time of it. We know, with hindsight, that he was predicting the brutal fall of Jerusalem in A.D. 70, by the Romans.

In 1 Timothy 4, Paul was *not* saying "It's ok to get married at a time of tribulation." To set those two texts in parallel, as if they were speaking of marrying at a time of tribulation is clearly not the case.  If Jesus had been indicating a time when it would be best not to get married, he would have given a clue about the time to stop getting married, say, around 65 A.D. He gave no such hint because he was not trying to stop anyone getting married, at any time.

Paul was speaking of people coming into the church at a future time, who would teach doctrines of demons. They would be liars. They would forbid people to marry; they would forbid people to eat certain foods.

Now we've got rid of those two red-herring texts, here is the answer to the actual question - "Is it good to marry at a time of tribulation?" Quite simply, when a time of tribulation erupts, it's too late to consider not marrying, or not procreating. But - worse - some people trying to control others in the church, by predicting a time of tribulation about to start, leading up to 'the end', can develop a track-record of warning their members not to get married, or, if married, not to have children till the danger is over. Here's one such historical record:

At a 1940 gathering, the group's president declared, “This might be the last assembly before the great tribulation.” He then advised the audience not to marry or have children. A lot of them paid heed, including a young married couple who postponed having children till 1946 (my parents).

In 1941 all the children from five to eighteen years of age were spoken to at another assembly. They were given a free copy of a new book which presented a fictional young couple who were engaged but who had decided to postpone their marriage until the arrival of the New Order which was so near at hand. "When the Theocracy is in full sway it will not be burdensome to have a family" (page 366).

1 November 1938 a magazine article was entitled, "Fill The Earth". It declared that Armageddon was just ahead and the survivors would be privileged to then fulfil the divine mandate to fill the earth. Thus, they should not marry and rear children because of the urgency of the work they had to do. On pages 324 and 324 the article categorically stated:

> "It would therefore appear that there is no reasonable or Scriptural
> injunction to bring children into the world immediately before
> Armageddon, where we now are."

Leaders revived this 'advice' around the 1970s. Once more, they were declaring their expectations for great tribulation to erupt. At an 1987 gathering, a discourse was given entitled "Responsible Childbearing in This Time of the End". It encouraged single persons to stay single and for married couples to remain childless to better serve in the work made necessary because of the nearness of Armageddon.

That November another article called, "Unmarried but Complete for God's Service" said, "But we must develop and control our circumstances so that the ministry is never relegated to a place that is less than central to our life (15 Nov 1987 issue). It commended those of the 1940s era who remained unmarried, free to serve the religious organisation. So, after a gap of about 30 years, it revived previous tactics that had worked so well in preventing marriages and children resulting.

That article and the following one, "Singleness, a Rewarding Way of Life", quoted 1 Timothy 4:3. They later published an article entitled, "Is This The Time to Have Children?" it said about their married couples who were devoted to the work:

> "They have chosen to remain childless so that they would be less
> encumbered to carry out the instructions of Jesus Christ to preach the
> good news of God's kingdom earth wide before the end of this system
> comes." 8 November 1974 issue

Even in 1996 pressure continued with an article called "Singleness - A Door to Undistracted Activity" being studied by all members worldwide (5 October 1996 issue.)

That's what's wrong with forbidding marriage or having children at an anticipated time of tribulation. It's a control mechanism to keep members of a religion working undistracted for the interests of the organisation.

Comment: +1 You're doing well in my book. Every time I read your answer, I have to readjust your weight in my book by increasing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what Jesus meant.
Its a spiritual teaching about apostasy and ones soul during the 6th Trump before the 7th (Second Advent).

Not about child birth literally.

Follow The Subject:
We do not marry to the false-Christ.
We wait for the Real Christ.

Technically Christ said it would be like in the Days of Noah, where they were giving and taking in marriage.  Matthew 24:37-39.

However in Noah's time they were doing that to the fallen angels.
(Jude and Genesis 6, Job 1 and 2. Revelation 12:9).

> 1 Corinthians 11:10 For this cause ought the woman to have power on
> her head because of the angels.

Christ is the bridegroom, as Christians we are the virgin bride.
He being away for 2k+ years, when He returns to find His bride to be with a child (worshiping false-Christ). It means she was unfaithful.

Read: 2 Thessalonians 2.

Having children and marriage is a blessing God commanded we should do.

However to be with child and nurse the child is a spiritual teaching equivalent to the mark in the forehead, and in the hand.
The bride did not wait for Jesus, instead she went with a false Jesus.
The union is apostasy. The bride then works for the false Jesus, nursing his lies along to herself and others. The mind put the hand to work for what it believes.

Matthew 24 the subject is false Christ shall rise.

> Matthew 24:23-25 (kjv)
>
> 23 Then if any man shall say unto you, Lo, here is Christ, or there;
> believe it not.
>
> 24 For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall
> shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they
> shall deceive the very elect.
>
> 25 Behold, I have told you before.

More detail about this is in Revelation 9 for how long this will even play out.  The whole of Satan's tribulation lasts for 5 months.

So that's really not much time to start a family anyway.
If you have a family already by that time, tell them The Truth. Care for them.

If you want to get married during the Trib go for it.
But make sure its not the fallen angels or antiChrist Satan.

There is a sinister teaching that has already taken root in most Christians concerning The Tribulation. It's not named that for the violence of that time no;  its because the gravity of the deception it brings that is so great is it a tribulation.

Satan will hold a revival and a time of peace, this world age has never seen. For this reason its dangerous. With most people being falsely taught its a time of war and destruction , they will be deceived.

> Some would differ with me on the length of time, but Christ said He
> shorted it.  Revelation 9 explains what that time is given the
> subject.
>
> I only mention that in passing. Since its not the subject of the thread I wont go
> into further detail.

Answer (score 1):

First - you need to discern the *audience*. Which are the *Jews*, not ‘us’ (church). We know this because that same verse talks about *the*  ‘sabbath’, and, verse 16 talks about Judea.

Second, we have an example of just what this event will be like. In 70AD Jerusalem *was* ransacked, and the historical eyewitness accounts recorded by Josephus are horrific - detailed, right down to what happened to pregnant mothers! Unimaginative! Luke’s account of the ‘Olivet discourse’ talks about this 70AD account.

So in other words we (now, with the help of history) have *clear* record of *exactly* what Jesus was meaning here in Matthew 24 - so we know it in *no way* talks about, suggests nor infers that you shouldn’t be married at this time. If we could infer *anything*? it would be a benefit to be married, because then you’d have someone to help you!

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to marry than to burn! Marriage is one good way to avoid sexual sin and Paul clearly teaches that it should not be prohibited. Jesus is not addressing marriage in his warning in Mt. 24. He is just giving practical advice that if you are trying to flee persecution by the Antichrist it will be difficult if you are pregnant or nursing. If you decide you need to get married as the end approaches, Jesus is suggesting that you try to avoid getting pregnant. How you do that is outside the scope of biblical hermeneutics:)

Answer (score -1):

The tribulatic endtimes might not come about until “the great falling away” first takes place. It would be then that the church loses its tares; and in the process gets greatly reduced and dispersed.

Unprecedented hardships would then make it too difficult  to bring up a family.  Thus, small children would be a too cumbersome addition to the  pursued faithful.

[2 Thess 2:3; Mat 13:24-43; 1 Cor 7:29,31; Mat 10:23]